# How to change an image resolution with Inkscape?

Tags: images, resolution, svg, inkscape

I'd like to know how can I change the pixel resolution of a SVG image made with Inkscape.

I've designed a square logo with a dimension of 25x25 millimeters, and when I saved it I noticed that the resulting image is just 88x88 pixels.

How can I increase the PPI value of this image?

Answer (score 4):

> As you are using vector graphics, the resolution doesn't really matter. It will matter if you export it to a bitmap or if you print it (as a bitmap, but you can also print as a vector in which case the resolution doesn't matter), at which times you will have to set a proper resolution.
>
> So you don't have to set the resolution on your image, if you export to bitmap in a different format than SVG you will have a field where you can set your resolution on the export dialog. If you print, you'll have to set the resolution on your printer (you'll probably find some option for it in the print dialog). If you are using bitmaps in your SVG file, make sure they are at the proper resolution before importing them into Inkscape.<sup>**1**</sup>

This also can be done by creating a new SVG image. Since SVG images and their behaviors are defined in XML text files, creating a new SVG image will eliminate the low resolution artifacts that were observed in your previous 25x25 millimeter SVG image.

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Rico's answer to [How do I set resolution in Inkscape?](https://answers.launchpad.net/inkscape/+question/65403)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Think about how big you want to print it. Printer resolution is usually 300 pixels per inch (ppi aka dpi).
So if you want to print it with a size of 1inch x 1 inch, you use the the file export dialogue (Shift+Ctrl+E) and set width and height to 300 .

Alternatively, if you created the image in the size, it should be printed (or just scale everything accordingly:

- Select everything with the selection tool (F1)
- Toggle the lock, to make sure scaling is proportionally
- also make sure, the four buttons on the right of the toolbar are selected, so that linewidth etc is scale accordingly
- enter desired size (you can change the units in the drop down box
- in the export tool choose the desired resolution (96 dpi for on-screen-display, 300 dpi for printing; the number of pixels will adjust accordingly

However, since logos are often used in pdfs nowadays keep in mind, that you are using vector graphics, and it truly only matters, if you use a pixelgraphic-format like png/jpg. If you stay in pdf for example, resolution doesn't matter. (as @karel already mentioned)

Comment: whoops. I just now realized, that this was asked a few months ago ;-)